# My PS4 is stuck on blue screen

Tags: ps4

I was trying to download rec room on my PS4 and then my screen went blue and I can't do anything. Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Try to unplug the console and then plug it back in. Ignore the messages on the startup(if they are about incorrect shutdown)